# Oracle ApEx Checkbox to Manipulate Other Values When Checked/Unchecked

Tags: javascript, sql, checkbox, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Firstly, I am using the latest version of Oracle ApEx 4.1.1 and have the following standard report that has a checkbox selection so when clicked, would like to set another field with sysdate, including time.

When unchecked, would like to reset to NULL the date set in my previous statement as well as a comments fields

Report might look like:

```
select id,
       name,
       telephone,
       apex_item.checkbox2(10,id) as "Tick when Contacted",
       apex_item.display_and_save(20,:P2_DATE) as "Date Contacted",
       apex_item.textarea(30,:P2_COMMENT,5,80) as "Comment"
from   my_table
```

As an example of the above report, there might be a total of 10 records, so as each of the 10 record checkboxes are checked by the user, I would like to set the date field to sysdate, on the spot. I would also like the reverse done, when the checkbox is unchecked - set both date and comments to NULL.

How should I approach this? Is the above possible via a Dynamic Action or straight via a JavaScript/on demand process?

Would definitely prefer the Dynamic Action approach if possible, in order to learn new methods of performing my required task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example on EMP table:

```
select 
apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx => 1, p_value => empno, p_attributes => 'class="check_select"') empselection,
apex_item.text(2, ename) empname,
empno,
ename
from emp
```

Add a class to the checkbox item. This makes it easy to target with jQuery.

Create a new dynamic action, eg "checkbox click".
**Event**: Click
**Selection** Type: jQuery Selector
**jQuery** Selector: `.check_select` (this is the class we added to the checkbox in the sql)
**Condition**: JavaScript Expression
**Value**: `$(this.triggeringElement).prop('checked')`

The condition is a check on the checkbox element to see whether it has been checked or unchecked. prop() tests a property of an element, and returns true or false in this case. When true, a true action will fire, else a false action.

**True Action:**
**Action**: Execute JavaScript Code
**Code**: `$(this.triggeringElement).closest("tr").find("td[headers='EMPNAME'] input").val('test');`

**False Action:**
**Action**: Execute JavaScript Code
**Code**: `$(this.triggeringElement).closest("tr").find("td[headers='EMPNAME'] input").val('');`

Both have no selection types since we need to target items in the same row as that of the clicked checkbox. There isn't really a way to do this through the apex selection possibilities. Target the column through the headers, and don't forget to target the input inside of the td (or: the `textarea`!)

When the dynamic action has been created, go back in. Under **Advanced** change the **Event Scope** to `Live`. This is necessary to account for pagination. If you don't change this, no actions will be bound to elements after pagination.

Then edit the true and false action, and **uncheck** `Fire on Page Load`.

Now to account for your date:
Since you want the sysdate as a default value, i'd suggest to add a hidden item to your page, eg P9_DEF_DATE. As a **source**, use a **PLSQL expression**, and use `SYSDATE`.
You can then use the value of that field as a default value, eg:

```
$(this.triggeringElement).closest("tr").find("td[headers='EMPNAME'] input").val($v('P9_DEF_DATE'));
```

Last note: blanking out a value through val: use `val('')` with **SINGLE** quotes! Won't work with double in my experience.

**Some links for Dynamic actions docs:**

- example by oracle (shows how to use plsql block in a dynamic action):
  http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/apex/r40/apexdynactions/apexdynactions_ll.htm
- Dimitri Gielis (some basics):
  http://dgielis.blogspot.be/search/label/Dynamic%20Actions
- Youtube tutorial by Dan McGhan:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JAKMU8x5nI
- And there is always plenty to find on the web of course, and don't
  forget the OTN forums.

**An example of an ajax process:**
So let's say that i want to update the COMM column of the employee i checked.

Create a new process on the page of the report, give it an easy enough name and don't put spaces in it. For example, i'm running with "update_emp".

```
update emp
set comm = apex_application.g_x02
where empno = apex_application.g_x01;
```

Add another true action to the dynamic action, type "Execute JavaScript Code".

```
$.post('wwv_flow.show', 
       {"p_request"      : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=update_emp',
        "p_flow_id"      : $v('pFlowId'), //app id
        "p_flow_step_id" : $v('pFlowStepId'), //page id
        "p_instance"     : $v('pInstance'), //session id
        "x01"            : $(this.triggeringElement).val(),
        "x02"            : '88', //just a bogus value to demonstrate
        },
        function(data){
           /*normally you'd handle the returned value here
             an example would be a JSON return with which to set item values*/
        }
        );
```

This javascript will post to the page, targetting the `update_emp` process. `x01` and `x02` are a sort of 'temp' variables. They exist so we don't have to submit page items all the time in order to post values to the session state. They are part of the apex_application package.
So here i'm using `x01` to store the empno (value of the checkbox, hence `this.triggeringElement`), and `x02` to pass in the value for the commision. I hardcoded it here but you can get any value you'd like of course.

`$.post` is a jQuery method posting to the page.

When you're learning dynamic actions or trawling forums, you may come across another method to post to the page, namely `htmldb_Get`, and this is built in in the apex javascript files. I don't use it because it is not true Ajax (asynchronous), but Sjax (synchronous), and is not transparant enough **in my opinion**. There is i believe some `GetAsync` part to it, which is good and all, but you'll barely ever see it used in any example. Now `get.get();` may look easy, and you can achieve the same result in 3 lines of code instead of my piece of js, consider it a good practice to implement real ajax calls. You might the wait to finish a process too much at times, and realise all those `htmldb_Get` calls in your applications aren't as fun as you think they were...

Things are also more complicated with this report setup. With page items you can take another route: instead of executing a javascript block you can execute a plsql code block. There you can specify items to be submitted to session state (so they can be used in the plsql block) and items to have their value set by this plsql block. (sql blocks are run server side, which means referenced items need to have their values in session sate). I'd advice to play around with that aswell.
That being said, you could do this with the report actions too, but you'd need to set up some bogus items to temporarily hold values which can then be submitted to session state. Again, i'm no fan of that so i didn't went with that (another 'imo' thus).

Essentially, have a browser inspection tool such as firebug open. It allows you to inspect ajax calls made on pages, and provides a great way to look into this.

Comment: Thanks Tom - you've really helped me alot. I was just wondering as I didn't mention this in my original post is that I also need to save these record changes to the database - now, can I do via the dynacmic action or do I need to loop through using array f01 and update each row that is checked? Thanks.

Comment: If you need to process each row and check whether the checkbox has been checked or not, then there is not much else to do than writing your own processing. It depends though on what exactly you mean: do you need to update these records the moment a change has been made to them (ie box is checked - save), or only when the page has been submitted? Own processing takes care of a page submit, but in the case of instant update you'd need more ajax.

Comment: Hi Tom, I actually would prefer the process of updating when the box is checked/unchecked as I actually don't want to have a "Submit" button. You mentioned ajax but unsure exactly if this is involved? Do I need to call an on demand process when the the checkbox is ticked, which would update the record? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do if you want this to happen instantly. Just for reference, dynamic actions and plenty of apex built-in functionalities involve ajax. For example, running a dynamic action which has a (pl)sql component involves a call to the server, easily observed by using (again, for example) firebug in firefox.

Comment: Thanks again Tom. Are you able to provide me an example of how to call/use on demand process via a Dynamic Action? Can you also provide any links to sites that explain Dynamic Actions as well as built-in functionalities. Thanks.

Comment: Tonsils: i have added some links and an ajax example that works in this context. It might be a bit true "stackoverflow" for you though if you're absolutely unfamiliar with this. I'd advise picking up some experience with dynamic actions and ajax calls in apex, and i'm sure it'll dawn on you as you go. There are other questions here on SO with examples, and there is plenty on the OTN forums and a lot of apex blogs with lots of information. And any questions, well, post em ;)

Comment: Tom: Again, you have been a great help with my queries and thorough examples and explanations. Kudos to you. I have a few questions before I accept your answer based on your latest response: 1) I am familiar with the htmldb_Get but with your .post example above, I am unsure if I have to add/use the function (data) json section or do I just leave it as is? 2) where exactly in firebug can I inspect the ajax calls made, i.e. what menu clicks to I need to click to see these calls? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Tom, just another question from the previous two questions: 3) Is the above process you have written, is this an on demand process?

Comment: 1) no, in this particular example the function is not required since the on-demand process is not supposed to return anything. It could be used to test succesfull return though. I mentioned json in the comment just to give an example of how you could use the return handler. 2) To view ajax calls, open firebug and select the console tab. You'll see lines added when they happen, and you can open up the details (such as post, response) 3) Yes, sorry for omitting that. It is indeed an on-demand process (page processing, ajax callbacks point)

Comment: Thanks Tom - if I could give you 10 votes I would. Hope you can assist with my new thread that I just raised on SO re: my original select above - APEX_ITEM api. Thanks.