# How to set a text item based on a selection list change event using a dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following select statement but unsure how to setup the dynamic action to assign the current sysdate when the user select
an option from with the LOV. I basically want to populate automatically the "DATE_CALLED" field to sysdate when a LOV selection is
made via a Dynamic Action.

Trying to use the same processing from this thread that was against a checkbox but cannot seem to work out - see:

[Oracle ApEx Checkbox to Manipulate Other Values When Checked/Unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038392/oracle-apex-checkbox-to-manipulate-other-values-when-checked-unchecked)

```
select  APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(1,change_id) ||
        APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(2,contact_id) ||
        APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(p_idx => 10,
                                       p_value => reason_id,
                                       p_lov => 'LOV_REASONS',
                                       p_attributes => 'class="lov_select"',
                                       p_show_null => 'YES',
                                       p_null_value => NULL,
                                       p_null_text => '--- Please select a reason ---') reas,
        APEX_ITEM.TEXT(p_idx => 20, 
                       p_value => TO_CHAR(date_contacted,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),
                       p_size => 14,
                       p_attributes => 'class="date_val" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#B0C4DE;border:1px solid #999999;"') "DATE_CALLED",
        APEX_ITEM.TEXTAREA(p_idx => 30,
                       p_value => comments,
                       p_rows => 2, 
                       p_cols => 30 ) "MPA_COMMENT"
from  MY_TABLE
```

For the Dymanic Action, I have the following:

```
Dynamic action: "lov selection"
Event: Change
Selection Type: jQuery Selector
jQuery Selector: .lov_select (this is the class I added to the select list from lov in the sql)
Condition: JavaScript Expression
Value: ****** Unsure what I need to put here ******
```

For True Action, I have the following:

```
True Action:
Sequence: 10
Action: Execute PL/SQl Code
Fire On Page Load: No
Code: :P1_DEF_DATE := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'); and have Page Item Submitted and Returned

Sequence: 20
Action: Execute JavaScript Code
Fire On Page Load: No
Code: $(this.triggeringElement).closest("tr").find("td[headers='DATE_CALLED'] input").val($v('P1_DEF_DATE'));
```

This code is not working as `$(this.triggeringElement)` is not correct for a select list.

How can I achieve what I need based on a select_list_from_lov scenario and not a checkbox?

Comment: It works when i try to set this up. Is there any error you're getting, or is some output not happening?

Comment: Tom, I am trying to get this working for a select list selection/change but no output is appearing in date field. What should the JavaScript expression value be - see above for this Dynamic Action definition. I can't seem to get this working and I really need to work this help, so would appreciate your help. .prop('checked') is used for checkboxes - what is it for a select list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the condition on the checkbox to distinguish between the checked/unchecked state, and to be able to define both true and false actions. You don't really need this on the checkbox: change will fire whenever the value changes (ie: user selects another option).

However, if you want to catch an invalid/null option you could use the condition, but instead of javascript expression use one of the operators to test the value (eg: "=" with "1")

To further elaborate on the action on your select list:
this is the query i used to set up an example:

```
select 
apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx => 1, p_value => empno, p_attributes => 'class="check_select"') empselection,
apex_item.text(2, :P14_DEF_TEXT) empname,
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(p_idx => 3,
                                       p_value => NULL,
                                       p_lov => 'LOV_REASONS',
                                       p_attributes => 'class="lov_select"',
                                       p_show_null => 'YES',
                                       p_null_value => NULL,
                                       p_null_text => '--- Please select a reason ---') reas,
apex_item.text(4, null) some_text,
empno,
ename,
comm
from emp
```

I used an lov with static values for `LOV_REASONS`.

[image: Dynamic action on lov select]

Code in True action:

```
$(this.triggeringElement).closest("tr").find("td[headers='SOME_TEXT'] input").val("THIS IS A TEST");
```

This seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I will try it again Tom and let you know. Just wondering, is there any way of debugging Dynamic Actions - thanks?

Comment: It kind of depends. At first i'd say: no, not built-in. Usually when something goes wrong, using a tool like Firebug in Firefox will help a great deal in tracking down what is going wrong. Executing javascript can also be reproduced in this manner: take the code and run it from the command window and see what it gives. Same with determining selectors. Running `$(".lov_select")` from the command window will show you in the console which elements have been selected. If your JS is really large, consider adding in some console.log lines, or use the same old alerts to trace your flow!

Comment: Thanks again Tom - that worked fine. Appreciate your help again.

Comment: Hi Tom, I seem to be having issues with my "When" condtion, specifically with trying to determine select option selection. Based on my LOV setup, I have 0,1,2 and 3 return IDs. In my "When" condition, I want the TRUE condition to fire when the value selected from Select List (LOV) is not equal to 0 and obviously the FALSE condition to fire when javascript expression equals 0. Can you please assist on how to capture this selection option value for rows 1, 3 and 5 of my sql report. I am unsure how to obtain correct selection option value based on my LOV. Thanks.

Comment: Tom, as per my previous comment, I need to be able to target each row in the report as separate records when it comes to making LOV selections. From what I can see, only the first LOV selection seems to be working. If for example I select ID 2 for this first LOV and then go and change the selection for record/row 3, the ID of 2 is still maintained. How can I make each record independant of each other for LOV? Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be careful with evaluating 0 in javascript, as zero also evaluates to false. See http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/ or any other resource. Use this for condition javascript expression: `$v(this.triggeringElement) > 0`. I don't really understand your last comment though, can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Tom, all good, I ended up using $(this.triggeringElement).val() > 0. I will try what you have pointed out too. Pls disregard my last comment. Thanks again.